# Dplyr's filter function doesn't work after Re-installation of R (3.5.2)

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

Due to some bug, I had to re-install R and R-studio.
I noticed that after the re-installation, some scripts that were running fine previously don't work anymore.

For example:

```
d1 <- tibble(Age = sample(seq(100, 200), 50))
```

(`tibble`: because apparently `data_frame` is deprecated???)

And now:

```
d1 %>% filter(Age < 150)
```

> Error in filter(., Age < 150) : object 'Age' not found.

Does this have anything to do with the new version of `dplyr`? `tidyverse`? or any other updates in R 3.5.2?

The only other thing I can think about is that I have some hidden files in the registry that were not properly un-installed.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error message. The code above works fine for me. (& yes, `data_frame` has been deprecated.) I'm on `R 3.5.2`, `dplyr 0.7.8`, and `tibble 2.0.1`.

Comment: Maybe reinstall the packages too and make sure you loaded them. Your code works fine for me on R 3.5.2, dplyr 0.8.0.1, and tibble 2.0.1.

Comment: I can reproduce your error if I forget to load the `dplyr` library. Then the function `stats::filter()` is used and that one can't find the object `Age`...